# apply similar variable to multiple dataset in r

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have 6 data named from dat1 to dat6, I want to add variable region and label them in a similar way, like this:

```
dat1$region <- paste("NE-1")
dat2$region <- paste("NE-2")
dat3$region <- paste("NE-3")
dat4$region <- paste("NE-4")
dat5$region <- paste("NE-5")
```

How can I write this code in a more concise way? using `apply` or `for-loop`?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `get` and `assign` functions in a `for-loop`.

**Sample data:**

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id=1:4, region = letters[1:4])
dat2 <- data.frame(id=5:8, region = letters[5:8])
dat3 <- data.frame(id=9:12, region = letters[9:12])
dat4 <- data.frame(id=13:16, region = letters[13:16])
dat5 <- data.frame(id=17:20, region = letters[17:20])

dat1
#   id region
# 1  1      a
# 2  2      b
# 3  3      c
# 4  4      d
```

Apply `for-loop`:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  name = paste("dat",i,sep="")
  temp <- get(name)
  temp$region = paste("NE",i,sep = "-")
  assign(name, temp)
}
```

**Verify results:**

```
dat1
#   id region
# 1  1   NE-1
# 2  2   NE-1
# 3  3   NE-1
# 4  4   NE-1


dat5
#   id region
# 1 17   NE-5
# 2 18   NE-5
# 3 19   NE-5
# 4 20   NE-5
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep all *dataframes* in a list then use *lapply*:

```
# example dataframes
dat1 <- cars[1:2, ]
dat2 <- cars[3:4, ]
dat3 <- cars[5:6, ]

myList <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
# myList 
# [[1]]
#   speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 
# [[2]]
#   speed dist
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 
# [[3]]
#   speed dist
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10
```

Then it is easier to do repetitive operations. Loop through the list, add *region* column:

```
res <- lapply(seq_along(myList), function(i){
  x <- myList[[ i ]]
  x$region <- paste0("NE-", i)
  x
})

res
# [[1]]
#   speed dist region
# 1     4    2   NE-1
# 2     4   10   NE-1
# 
# [[2]]
#   speed dist region
# 3     7    4   NE-2
# 4     7   22   NE-2
# 
# [[3]]
#   speed dist region
# 5     8   16   NE-3
# 6     9   10   NE-3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (assuming all your items start with `dat` and end with a unique identifier string):

```
dat_names <- ls()[grepl("^dat", ls())]
dat_ID <- sapply(dat_names, function(d) gsub("dat", "", d))
for(d in 1:length(dat_names)) {
  dat_names[[d]]$region <- paste("NE-", dat_ID[d], sep="")
}
```